# Php post array data to server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have some number which are generated randomly . I need to get these numbers on server side i.e.$POST['number_array'].This "number_array" should include all the randomly generated numbers .Can anybody suggest me some way to do this. I am using PHP , Jquery , Javascript

Comment: Do you mean: $_POST['number_array']?

Comment: I don't know what did you do in client side: how about your html, javascript?

Comment: on client side i already have an array which has these number.. I just need to send this to server side . I am using javascript on client side

Answer (score 1):

your GET/POST request should look like this:

```
number_array[]=1&number_array[]=2&number_array[]=5
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `[]`s after the name of the form element.

```
<input type="text" name="number_array[]" />
<input type="text" name="number_array[]" />
etc.
```

Then you can access the variables like so:

```
$number_array = $POST['number_array'];
$number_array[0];
```

Comment: But how do i insert those numbers in random[]

Comment: You said you already have "some number which are generated randomly". Just put them into the `number_array[]` textboxes using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an ajax call, you can do it with jquery:

```
$.post("test.php", { 'number_array[]': [65, 45] }, function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
}););
```

EDIT: both `'number_array[]': [65, 45]` and  `'number_array': [65, 45]` works fine, and `"` around javascript arrays are optional

Comment: I don't think that your fucntion is correct:
You must `number_array: ["65", "45"]`, because `["65", "45"]` is array.

Answer (score 0):

Let me summary what you need:

Client side with javascript

```
<script>
    //If you have an array with 3 items with random value
    var arrInt = [Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random()];
    //If you want to send it to file yourscript.php
    //1. Using GET mothod
    /*
    $.get(
        'yourscript.php',        
        {
            number_array: arrInt
        }
    );
    */
    //2. Using POST method:
    $.post(
        'yourscript.php',        
        {
            number_array: arrInt
        }
    );
</script>
```

Server side with PHP:

```
<?php
    //$arrInt = $_GET['number_array'];//If using GET
    $arrInt = $_POST['number_array'];//If using POST
    print $arrInt[0];
    print $arrInt[1];
    print $arrInt[2];
?>
```

Comment: exactly this is how i need.. let me try this